# Postgres: get all columns from all views in schema

Tags: postgresql

I want all columns from all views within a schema in my PostgreSQL database.
I can find similar information for all tables using the following query:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name'
```

What would be the equivalent for views instead of tables?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23836/how-to-list-all-views-in-sql-in-postgresql#answer-23837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just join against pg_class for relation type

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
join pg_class on table_name = relname and relnamespace=table_schema::regnamespace
where relkind = 'v'
;
```